# Tkinter canvas fails to delete item

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I have been tinkering with a python problem where i am using tkinter to make drawings on applying canvas.delete(args) from tkinter, nothing happens .I am using print statements to help in debugging item ids appear the same as the ones used in creating the items please assist.
Here is part of my code

```
lst = []
lst1 = []
lst2 = []
class A1:

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.canvas_width = 700
        self.canvas_height = 400
        master.title("A1 - StudentUPI") 
        geometry_string = str(self.canvas_width)+"x"+str(self.canvas_height)+"+10+20"
        master.geometry(geometry_string)
        self.a_canvas = Canvas(root)
        self.a_canvas.config(background="SlateBlue1")   
        self.a_canvas.pack(fill=BOTH, expand = True)
        self.create_button()
        self.coord = RandRegion.RandRegion(self.canvas_width,self.canvas_height)

    def create_button(self):
        self.frame = Frame(root, bg='grey', width=700, height=40)
        self.frame.pack(fill='x')
        self.button1 = Button(self.frame, text='Add Rect', command=self.randRect)
        self.button1.pack(side='left')
        self.button2 = Button(self.frame, text='Remove Rect', command=self.remRec)
        self.button2.pack(side='left')
        self.button3 = Button(self.frame, text='Add Circle', command=self.randCircle)
        self.button3.pack(side='left')
        self.button4 = Button(self.frame, text='Remove Circle', command=self.remCir)
        self.button4.pack(side='left')
        self.button5 = Button(self.frame, text='Add Arc', command=self.randArc)
        self.button5.pack(side='left')
        self.button6 = Button(self.frame, text='Remove Arc', command=self.remArc)
        self.button6.pack(side='left')
        self.button7 = Button(self.frame, text='Remove Red Shapes', command=self.remRed)
        self.button7.pack(side='left')

    def randRect(self):
        coord = RandRegion.RandRegion(self.canvas_width,self.canvas_height).get_coord()
        color = RandRegion.RandRegion(self.canvas_width,self.canvas_height).get_color()
        lst.append([coord,color])
        self.a_canvas.create_rectangle(coord,fill=color)
        print(coord)

    def randCircle(self):
        coord = RandRegion.RandRegion(self.canvas_width,self.canvas_height).get_coord()
        color = RandRegion.RandRegion(self.canvas_width,self.canvas_height).get_color()
        lst1.append([coord,color])
        self.a_canvas.create_oval(coord,fill=color)
        print(lst1)

    def randArc(self):
        coord = RandRegion.RandRegion(self.canvas_width,self.canvas_height).get_coord()
        color = RandRegion.RandRegion(self.canvas_width,self.canvas_height).get_color()
        lst2.append([coord,color])
        self.a_canvas.create_arc(coord, start=0, extent=90,fill=color)
        print(lst2)

    def remRec(self):
        self.a_canvas.delete(str(lst[random.randrange(len(lst))][0]))
        print((lst[random.randrange(len(lst))][0]))

    def remCir(self):
        self.a_canvas.delete(str(lst1[random.randrange(len(lst1))][0]))

    def remArc(self):
        self.a_canvas.delete(lst2[random.randrange(len(lst2))][0])

    def remRed(self):
        new_lis = lst 
        for x in range(len(new_lis)):
            if 'red' in (new_lis[x]):
                print(new_lis[x][0])
                self.a_canvas.delete(new_lis[x][0])


    print(lst,lst1,lst2)


root = Tk()
app = A1(root)
root.mainloop()
`
```

Answer (score 1):

[canvas.delete(item)](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.delete-method) takes *Item specifier (tag or id)* as parameter. So you should assign your creations(`a_canvas.create_xxx( )`) to a variable, then delete them using those variables.

An example for your Arcs:

```
def randArc(self):
    ....
    arc = self.a_canvas.create_arc(coord, start=0, extent=90,fill=color)
    lst2.append(arc)

def remArc(self):
    # you need to remove that item from list as well
    removed_arc = lst2.pop(random.randrange(len(lst2))) 
    self.a_canvas.delete(removed_arc)
```

Comment: Thanks I finally figured that out